# Audioplayer with parsing data

Tags: ios

I am trying to make an online audio player with the help of json parsing. Data is coming but when I am passing the value to audio player, then it is not playing song. 
My code is below:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *strr=[tabledata objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
//table data is mutable array which has all the links to top ten songs
    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:strr];

    _ap=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url error:nil];

    [_ap play];

}
```

Comment: have you checked the URL is good?

Comment: I think it is possible that the format of you audio file is not supported

Comment: i hv checked but its not working..

Answer (score 0):

you can find the sample code for it

[Sample program 1](http://www.raywenderlich.com/69369/audio-tutorial-ios-playing-audio-programatically-2014-edition)